How can I set sameSite to 'none' if I want next-intl to work when someone embeds my site in an iframe?
I have an application that I can embed in an iframe, where users can manually switch languages. This functionality works well in the main application, but I'm encountering issues with the iframe due to SameSite cookie restrictions, which prevent cookies from being changed.
I'm looking for a way to set the SameSite attribute to "None" for these cookies. I prefer not to use localStorage, as I'm working with Next.js and want to keep the calls on the server. I have a backend in place and would like to read the language cookie from there.
